# How do I change the value of the label every tick event C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, variables, timer

I am trying to make a "blinking" type of effect in my C# project, by that I mean that I want a label to switch text every tick.. And I've come to mind that the easiest way to do this would be by using a timer event to change the label text every tick once the start button is being pressed.
This is a WinForm Application

But I dont know how to make the label switch values after every tick

I think I am making this harder than it should be..

What my code does now is that it tries to change the myLabel1 to firstBlinkName; AND secondBlinkName; at the same time.. I would like some time in between, I really dont know how to do this.

```
private void nameBlinkInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstBlinkName = nameBlinkFirstName.Text;
    var secondBlinkName = nameBlinkSecond.Text;
    myLabel1.text = firstBlinkName;
    myLabel1.text = secondBlinkName;
}
```

Sorry for bad naming conventions!

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, what timer are you using - can you show the code where you set the timer up..

Comment: @Nilsson: Do you want to create the label dyanamically?

Comment: The object can be created programattically or in xml. Also I think c# naming convention is to capitalize all variable name first letters for methods and variable or types. Like `NewFunction( int varThatGoesInFunction). There is a msdn article about it. Also not sure what prospector is talking about, is it a html to be ran on client side browser? Otherwise if typical windows c# app he is completely wrong.

Comment: Also what type of object has the text that will be flashing?

Comment: change the objects textblock.text in c# inside `main()` inside program.cs

Comment: added a better description.. I dont know how to make the label switch values after every tick

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @marshalcraft Why would I want to switch around with the textboxes?...

Comment: Your own words "asiest way to do this would be by using a timer event to change the label text every..."

Comment: After setting the new text in the Tick also tell the label to Refresh itself! Aslo: Test the current values and change when needed: `l.Text = l.Text==A?:B:A;`

Comment: In your name you have called it a "textbox" which is a forms class which has a text property. Why don't you be clear and tell us precisely the object type which is to be altered periodically.

Answer (score 2):

This will test, change each time and refresh the label:

```
private void nameBlinkInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var firstBlinkName = nameBlinkFirstNameTextBox.Text;
   var secondBlinkName = nameBlinkSecondTextBox.Text;

   labelThatWillBlink.Text =  labelThatWillBlink.Text  == firstBlinkName ?
                              secondBlinkName  : firstBlinkName ;
   labelThatWillBlink.Refresh();
}
```

Note the use of the [`ternary operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I'm i get you correctly, If your requirement is to toggle some text on the label in each Tick. If so you should keep one global variable that will increase its value in each Tick. Following code will help you

```
int tikCount=0; // This will be a global variable
string firstBlinkName = "some string Here";
string secondBlinkName = "Some other string";
private void nameBlinkInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelThatWillBlink = tikCount++ %2 ==0? firstBlinkName:secondBlinkName;
   // then do something here that will switch the labelThatWillBlink's value to secondBlinkName

}
```

Comment: I tried that and it only seemed to change it to the firstName without switching over to the other one after the correct ammount of time

Comment: How do you detect the text is changing?

Answer (score 0):

```
myLabel1.Text = "firstText";

private void nameBlinkInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(myLabel1.Text == "firstText")
    {
        myLabel1.Text = "secondText";
    }
    else
    {
        myLabel1.Text = "firstText";
    }
}
```

Just check if the labels contains the firstText and if that is true, set the label to the secondText. If the label doesn't contain the firstText anymore the second Tick, it puts the label back to firstText.